# Combine Data Wrangling workflow into a single function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have got a list of dataframes where I want to perform some data wrangling operations on. For every year, I got a new list of data.frames

```
results_2018 <- list_of_objects %>%
    map(~dplyr::top_n(.x, 10, Germany)) %>%
    map(~rename(.x, "Answers" = "Answer.Options"))

results_2019 <- list_of_objects_2 %>%
    map(~dplyr::top_n(.x, 10, Germany)) %>%
    map(~rename(.x, "Answers" = "Data.Points"))
```

This is my code where I calculate the top 10 values for each year for one country. Since there are 10 years in history, is there a way to comebine these calculations into a single function?
I guess `map2` and `pmap` might do the job, but I can´t get my head around how this works.

Can anyone help me? (sorry for not providing reproduceable data, datasets are quite large)

Comment: Does `list_of_objects` have multiple dataframes in them?

Comment: yes, but their column structure is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(tidyverse)

list_obj <- list(list_of_objects, list_of_objects_2, ..., ..)
#If there are lot of them use
#list_obj <- mget(ls(pattern = 'list_of_objects\\d+'))

output <- map(list_obj, ~map(.x, function(x) 
           x %>% top_n(10, Germany) %>% rename("Answers" = "Answer.Options"))
```

This would return you list of lists, possibly using `map_df` for inner `map` would be useful.

```
map(list_obj, ~map_df(.x, function(x) 
           x %>% top_n(10, Germany) %>% rename("Answers" = "Answer.Options"))
```